# Angular.js: Unable to display user properties in the view using ng-repeat and handle-bars

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, postgresql

Angular.js, Node.js, Postgresql

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var pathfinderUI = require('pathfinder-ui');
var engines = require('consolidate');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('html', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'html');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// pathfinder
app.use('/pathfinder', function(req, res, next){
    pathfinderUI(app)
    next()
}, pathfinderUI.router)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

public/javascripts/user.js:

```
var app = angular.module('sendgrid-webhook', [])
app.controller('mainController', ($scope, $http) => {
  $scope.formData = {};
  // Get all users
  $http.get('api/v1/users')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.userData = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    });
    // Create a new todo
  $scope.createUser = () => {
    $http.post('/api/v1/users', $scope.formData)
    .success((data) => {
      $scope.formData = {};
      $scope.userData = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
    .error((error) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
    });
  };
  // Delete a todo
  $scope.deleteUser = (userID) => {
    $http.delete('/api/v1/users/' + todoID)
    .success((data) => {
      $scope.userData = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
    .error((data) => {
      console.log('Error: ' + data);
    });
  };
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sendgrid-webhook">
  <head>
    <title>SendGrid JS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Username" ng-model="formData.username">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email Address" ng-model="formData.email">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" ng-model="formData.password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="createUser()">Create User</button>
      </form>
      <div class="user-list">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="user in userData"><input type="checkbox" ng-click="deleteUser(user.id)">
            {{ user.username }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSON Response:

```
[{"id":1,"username":"test","email":"test@test.com","password":"newpass"},{"id":4,"username":"First","email":"first@gmail.com","password":"test"},{"id":5,"username":"Tesing a third user","email":"newemail@gmail.com","password":"testing"}]
```

Console Log Object:

[userData Object in Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fLD3.png)

On line 6 in app.js, I am making an API call to the users endpoint that returns the proper array of user objects. That is saved as '$scope.userData'. When I was a debugger to check in return value I get an array of three users. If you look at the index.html, you can see the checkboxes being created for each.

On line 24 in index.html I am setting the 'li' element with 'ng-repeat="user in userData"'. Within each of those 'li' elements, I wish to display a user's properties with {{ user.username }}.

My view is iterating over the array of user objects, and creating the 'li' for each them, but why are the handlebars not displaying the user.username property I am requesting?

EDIT:

[It works in Plunker when I replace the AJAX call with the response data from the console](https://plnkr.co/edit/MKtaE8mnQeZ3g3qbL1du?p=preview)

But the dir structure is different too and node isn't involved.

Comment: Please embed your code in the post, and do not post pictures of code.

Comment: `log` the userData and check the structure of the json (much more better if you paste it in the question)

Comment: What is in the first array ?

Comment: I added the response and an image of the expanded object.

Comment: your code works fine for me

Comment: I substituted your api for my own, of course.

Comment: Jace, I can get the code to work when I hard code the response with an array of objects. But the usernames do not appear when iterating over the object from the API call.

Comment: @Claies, I did that with the same result. usernames still do not appear in the view. There are li's for each user object, but the {{ }} simply don't interpret in the browser.

Comment: [It works in Plunker when I replace the AJAX call with the response data from the console](https://plnkr.co/edit/MKtaE8mnQeZ3g3qbL1du?p=preview)

But the dir structure is different too and node isn't involved.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

I was serving the view form the `/views` folder. Now, the html was being served to the browser just fine, but, because of the way express serves its static assets with Angular(?), I needed to move the index.html view into the public folder in the file tree. A drag and drop, and the `{{ }}` notation works fine.

Thanks for the help anyone. If you would like some clarification, let me know!

PS: Post everything, even your Dir Struct on Q&A, it probably would have helped me here.